# Linux segmentation fault

Tags: linux, c, segmentation-fault

When I run this program I get segmentation fault, and I could not find it's origin. 
I don't know how to deal with it. 
Could you help me?

This is my code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    static int func(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
      char msg[500]="sdfsdf";

      argv[0]="sdf grgrg";

      printf("%s",argv[0]);

      argv[0]='\0';

      strcpy(argv[0],msg);

      printf("%s",argv[0]);

      return 0;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
      func(argc, argv);
      //printf("sdfasf");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on these lines.

```
argv[0]='\0';
strcpy(argv[0],msg);
```

It's irrelevant that this is `argv[0]`, so I'll introduce a variable:

```
char *var = '\0';
strcpy(var, msg);
```

Then, recall that `'\0'` is an integer literal with value zero, so when it is assigned to a pointer variable it becomes a null pointer:

```
char *var = NULL;
strcpy(var, msg);
```

We can inline the variable:

```
strcpy(NULL, msg);
```

Whoops!  Don't do that.  That will crash, or worse--it might *not* crash.

Comment: Actually that's wrong, because `argv[0]='\0'` does assign `'\0'` to the place `argv` points to while `char *var='\0'` creates a char pointer which points to `NULL`.. So `strcpy(NULL,msg)` is not the same  as `strcpy(argv[0],msg)` (BTW `strcpy` needs char pointers and not `argv[0]` which is a single char)
Or am I totally wrong here? :D

Comment: @Uroc327: Yes, you are totally wrong here (since you asked...).  Remember that `argv` has type `char **`, not `char *`, so `argv[0]` has type `char *`.